# Using @RestClientTest in spring boot test

Tags: spring-boot, spring-rest, spring-boot-test

I want to write a simple test using `@RestClientTest` for the component below (*NOTE:* I can do it without using `@RestClientTest` and mocking dependent beans which works fine.).

```
@Slf4j
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class NotificationSender {

    private final ApplicationSettings settings;
    private final RestTemplate restTemplate;

    public ResponseEntity<String> sendNotification(UserNotification userNotification)
            throws URISyntaxException {
            // Some modifications to request message as required
            return restTemplate.exchange(new RequestEntity<>(userNotification, HttpMethod.POST, new URI(settings.getNotificationUrl())), String.class);
    }
}
```

And the test;

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@RestClientTest(NotificationSender.class)
@ActiveProfiles("local-test")
public class NotificationSenderTest {

    @MockBean
    private ApplicationSettings settings;
    @Autowired
    private MockRestServiceServer server;
    @Autowired
    private NotificationSender messageSender;

    @Test
    public void testSendNotification() throws Exception {
        String url = "/test/notification";
        UserNotification userNotification = buildDummyUserNotification();
        when(settings.getNotificationUrl()).thenReturn(url);
        this.server.expect(requestTo(url)).andRespond(withSuccess());

        ResponseEntity<String> response = messageSender.sendNotification(userNotification );

        assertThat(response.getStatusCode()).isEqualTo(HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    private UserNotification buildDummyUserNotification() {
     // Build and return a sample message
    }
}
```

But i get error that `No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate' available`. Which is right of course as i havn't mocked it or used `@ContextConfiguration` to load it.

Isn't `@RestClientTest` configures a `RestTemplate`? or i have understood it wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? _For testing such a REST client built with RestTemplateBuilder, you may use a SpringRunner-executed test class annotated with `@RestClientTest`. This annotation disables full auto-configuration and only applies configuration relevant to REST client tests, i.e. Jackson or GSON auto-configuration and `@JsonComponent` beans, **but not regular `@Component` beans**._

Comment: @Patrick Yes i saw that but no where is says that the `unit under test` should not be a component bean.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found it! Since i was using a bean that has a `RestTemplate` injected directly, we have to add `@AutoConfigureWebClient(registerRestTemplate = true)` to the test which solves this.

This was in the javadoc of `@RestClientTest` which i seem to have ignored previously.

Test which succeeds;

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@RestClientTest(NotificationSender.class)
@ActiveProfiles("local-test")
@AutoConfigureWebClient(registerRestTemplate = true)
public class NotificationSenderTest {

    @MockBean
    private ApplicationSettings settings;
    @Autowired
    private MockRestServiceServer server;
    @Autowired
    private NotificationSender messageSender;

    @Test
    public void testSendNotification() throws Exception {
        String url = "/test/notification";
        UserNotification userNotification = buildDummyUserNotification();
        when(settings.getNotificationUrl()).thenReturn(url);
        this.server.expect(requestTo(url)).andRespond(withSuccess());

        ResponseEntity<String> response = messageSender.sendNotification(userNotification );

        assertThat(response.getStatusCode()).isEqualTo(HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    private UserNotification buildDummyUserNotification() {
     // Build and return a sample message
    }
}
```