# How to use @RestTemplateClient with JUnit 5?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, spring-boot-test

I use spring boot 2.1.7.RELEASE and junit 5. Unfortunately, I have problem with @RestClientTest, because I'm getting java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to use auto-configured MockRestServiceServer since MockServerRestTemplateCustomizer has not been bound to a RestTemplate. Do you have any ideas how to configure this correctly?

Similar code works perfectly in junit 4. 
Source code is based on documentation https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html.

Source code:

```java
@RestClientTest(RemoteVehicleDetailsService.class)
public class ExampleRestClientTest {

    @Autowired
    private RemoteVehicleDetailsService service;

    @Autowired
    private MockRestServiceServer server;

    @Test
    public void getVehicleDetailsWhenResultIsSuccessShouldReturnDetails()
            throws Exception {
        this.server.expect(requestTo("/greet/details"))
                .andRespond(withSuccess("hello", MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN));
        String greeting = this.service.callRestService();
        assertThat(greeting).isEqualTo("hello");
    }
```

Exception:

````
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to use auto-configured MockRestServiceServer since MockServerRestTemplateCustomizer has not been bound to a RestTemplate

    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:73)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.client.MockRestServiceServerAutoConfiguration$DeferredRequestExpectationManager.getDelegate(MockRestServiceServerAutoConfiguration.java:110)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.client.MockRestServiceServerAutoConfiguration$DeferredRequestExpectationManager.expectRequest(MockRestServiceServerAutoConfiguration.java:87)
    at org.springframework.test.web.client.MockRestServiceServer.expect(MockRestServiceServer.java:107)
    at org.springframework.test.web.client.MockRestServiceServer.expect(MockRestServiceServer.java:92)
    at ExampleRestClientTest.getVehicleDetailsWhenResultIsSuccessShouldReturnDetails(ExampleRestClientTest.java:27)```
````

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tested your case with the last spring boot 2.1.7 and junit 5 and everything is working fine. Please try :

pom.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.zpavel</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.7.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <version>1.4.199</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>junit</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

application.properties (i used h2 in-memory database) :

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

FooService.java :

```
@Service
public class FooService {

    private final RestTemplate restTemplate;

    public FooService(RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder) {
        this.restTemplate = restTemplateBuilder.build();
    }

    public String getIndex() {
        String result = restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:8080", String.class);
        System.out.println("index: " + result);
        return result;
    }
}
```

FooServiceTest.java :

```
@RestClientTest(FooService.class)
public class FooServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    private FooService service;

    @Autowired
    private MockRestServiceServer server;

    @Test
    public void testIndex() throws Exception {
        this.server.expect(requestTo("http://localhost:8080")).andRespond(withSuccess("hello", MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN));
        String greeting = this.service.getIndex();
        assertEquals(greeting, "hello");
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a heads up on the imports: import static org.springframework.test.web.client.match.MockRestRequestMatchers.method;
import static org.springframework.test.web.client.match.MockRestRequestMatchers.requestTo;
import static org.springframework.test.web.client.response.MockRestResponseCreators.withStatus;

Comment: This works for me. Note: FooService autowires using RestTemplateBuilder. If it autowires using RestTemplate, FooServiceTest needs to add @AutoConfigureWebClient(registerRestTemplate = true) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54434637/using-restclienttest-in-spring-boot-test

Answer (score 1):

Would spring MockMvc work for you?

```
@Autowired
private MockMvc mockMvc;

public void test() {
    this.mockMvc.perform(get("/form")
            .header(AUTHORIZATION, authHeader))
            .andDo(print())
            .andExpect(status().isOk());
}
```